# Inequality: double jensen, is this correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality

Imagine I have an exponent $a=bc$ where $b>1$ and $0<c<1$, the product $a=bc\in \mathbb{R}$ might be greater, equal or less than 1. Then for a measurable set with measure 1. Can I say the following? (double Jensen's inequality)

$$E\left[\left(\int_A f\right)^{a}\right]\leq E\left[\left(\int_A f^b\right)^{c}\right]\leq E\left[\int_A f^b\right]^c.$$

It feels correct (first Jensen's w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, and then w.r.t. probability measure) but it also feels like cheating :)

Thanks for the help!